# R merge multiple files into 1 dataframe and keep all values

Tags: r, merge, semi-join

I have 6 multiple files, each having only 1 column of names. I want to read all these files and combine them in 1 dataframe so that it looks like this:

```
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5  file6
adam   adam   adam   adam   adam   adam
Roy    NA     Roy    Roy    NA     NA
NA     Sam    Sam    NA     NA     NA
```

The `colnames` of resulting dataframe should represent the actual file names. Let's say that the file I read were named `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and so on..

Any help will be much appreciated.

What I've been trying so far:

```
multmerge = function(mypath){
+ filenames=list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE, pattern = "\\.txt$")
+ datalist = lapply(filenames, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=F)})
+ Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y, all.x=T)}, datalist)}
> mymergeddata = multmerge("/Path/To/The/Folder/Having/All/Files")
> dim(mymergeddata)
[1] 11508     1
```

As seen here it is combining all values (`names`) in one column..

Comment: Rather than the `Reduce` line, try `do.call(cbind,datalist)`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 11508, 10307, 9917, 9798, 12167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do that with rbindlist and dcast from data.table

```
library(data.table)
file_list <- list.files("c:/temp/files/",full.names = TRUE)
import_files <- lapply(file_list,read.csv,stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
rbinded_files <- na.omit(rbindlist(import_files,idcol="file"))
dcast(rbinded_files,file1 ~file,fun=max, na.rm=TRUE)

  file1    1    2    3    4    5    6
1  adam adam adam adam adam adam adam
2   Roy  Roy <NA>  Roy  Roy <NA> <NA>
3   Sam <NA>  Sam  Sam <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

You can remove the first column if you want.

Comment: I tried your solution but the last line of dcast gives me error: `Using 'V1' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'file1' not found`

Comment: There was a typo mistake there, the dcast will be used as: `dcast(rbinded_files, V1 ~ file, fun=max, na.rm=T)`

Answer (score 1):

This is not probably the most efficient, but the function should do the trick and I'd be happy to hear about ways to improve the function as I'm a stack newbie:

```
library(data.table); library(tidyverse)

multmerge <- function(dir) {
    # Load files and bind columns
    full_dir_filenames <- list.files(path = dir, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "\\.txt$")
    datalist <- lapply(full_dir_filenames, read_csv, col_names = FALSE) %>% 
        lapply(t) %>% 
        lapply(as.tibble)
    df <- bind_cols(datalist)

    # Append the column names
    file_names <- list.files(path = dir, full.names = FALSE, pattern = "\\.txt$")
    col_names <- tstrsplit(file_names, split = "[.]")[[1]]
    colnames(df) <- col_names

    df
}

multmerge()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `purrr::map`

```
files <- list.files("/path/",full.names = TRUE)

combinedDF <- files %>% map(read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, col.names=files) %>% 
  reduce(cbind)
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 11507, 10306`

Comment: @Newbie Ahh, I forgot cbind has to be passed columns with an equal number of rows. For the above to work, you'd have to fill each column with NA's to match the length of the longest column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of your function that gives the output you asked for...

```
multmerge <- function(mypath){
  filenames <- list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE, pattern = "\\.txt$")
  datalist <- lapply(filenames, function(x){
            df <- read.csv(file=x,header=F,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
            df[,2] <- gsub("\\.txt","",basename(x))
            return(df)})
  namesdf <- do.call(rbind,datalist)
  output <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(namesdf$name,namesdf$file))
  for(j in 1:nrow(output)){
    output[j,] <- ifelse(as.numeric(output[j,])==0,NA,row.names(output)[j])
  }
  return(output)
}
```

Comment: Thank youf or taking out time to suggest a solution. This function only returns this: `data frame with 0 columns and 1 row`